# To check whether improper integral converges or not $\int_{-1}^1 \frac{(x-1)}{x^{5/3}}dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, improper-integrals

Given integral is

$$\int_{-1}^1 \frac{(x-1)}{x^{5/3}}dx$$

**ATTEMPT**

Since there are no problem spots here. so i evaluated integral directly and got some answer. But textbook says integral is divergent. Can you please let me know where i am going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Hint: what if $x=0$?

Comment: @MichaelGaluza ok after spliting i get $\int_{0}^1 \frac{(x-1)}{x^{5/3}}dx$ as my second piece. By comparison with $1/x^{5/3}$ i conclude it is divergent. Is this right?

Answer (score 0):

We see that at $x=0$ integrand is undefined. So,
$$
\int_{-1}^1 \frac{x-1}{x^{5/3}}dx = \lim_{\substack{\epsilon_1\to+0\\\epsilon_2\to+0}} \left(\int_{-1}^{-\epsilon_1} \frac{x-1}{x^{5/3}}dx + \int_{-\epsilon_1}^{\epsilon_2} \frac{x-1}{x^{5/3}}dx + \int_{\epsilon_2}^1 \frac{x-1}{x^{5/3}}dx\right)
$$
As you can see, second integral is diverges.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int\left(\frac{x-1}{x^{\frac{5}{3}}}\right)\text{d}x=$$

---

Substitute $u=\sqrt[3]{x}$ and $\text{d}u=\frac{1}{3x^{\frac{2}{3}}}\text{d}x$:

---

$$3\int\left(\frac{u^3-1}{u^3}\right)\text{d}u=$$
$$3\int\left(1-\frac{1}{u^3}\right)\text{d}u=$$
$$3\left(\int\left(1\right)\text{d}u-\int\left(\frac{1}{u^3}\right)\text{d}u\right)=$$
$$3\left(u-\int\left(\frac{1}{u^3}\right)\text{d}u\right)=$$
$$3\left(u+\frac{1}{2u^2}\right)+C=$$
$$3\left(\sqrt[3]{x}+\frac{1}{2(\sqrt[3]{x})^2}\right)+C=$$
$$\frac{3(2x+1)}{2x^{\frac{2}{3}}}+C$$

If you now turn in your boundaries you'll see it won't work! It diverges